# rails 5 full engine name same as model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5. I've added my own rails engine with `--full` setup.

```
rails plugin new wallet --full
```

I've added this in my root Gemfile:

```
gem 'wallet', path: 'engines/wallet'
```

My engine name called wallet.

In my engine, I added a model called Wallet. When I try to access Wallet model in view or from console, it shows as String type "Wallet"

Is this how it's supposed to work? What if I would like to access module "Wallet" from root app? I'm not sure of any way to work this out.

Comment: you want to override the module of wallet gem?

Comment: Hi, no, my intention is to call model Wallet, but it seems to return String instead of the class Wallet

Comment: How you calling the model? Can you show us the codebase?

Comment: within view template: Wallet.model_name.human (Wallet.model_name already failed)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any better solution. but from my experience, like spree gem, they are doing both `--full` and `--mountable` gem. My solution is to rename engine with prefix engine_ to avoid having same model name with engine name.

I hope someone have a better solution.